# Получение списка баз данных, подключенных к серверу

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

Имеется веб-приложение в NetBeans и есть несколько MySQL баз данных, подключенных к серверу через JDBC. Подскажите, как можно в приложении получить список подключенных БД или какими ещё инструментами возможно релизовать искомое?

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову: занести в properties файл, и от туда тянуть

Comment: баз данных или серверов баз? список баз на сервере  SHOW DATABASES.

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL получить список баз данных можно при помощи запроса

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

или обращением к информационной схеме

```
SELECT
  SCHEMA_NAME
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```